# Why are my excel workbooks invisible in Excel 2010?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-2010

I've been running an excel export function with .xlsx files.  Occasionally when loading an excel file I use the System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker() method.  When the file in question is *not* open, but exists, i get the following results:

Excel will start, but the workbook will not load, and neither will any worksheets.  Excel appears blank.

When opening the file outside of the program that performs the exporting, it loads in exactly the same way.  Excel is open, it says Microsoft Excel at the top of the window, but there are no visible sheets.  Excel looks like there is nothing open at all.

Going into the options also suggests that there are no workbooks open.  The file definitely has content though, as I can see when I open it in Notepad++ The document has enough detail for me to see that there are sheets in the workbook, but nothign shows up.

I'm not sure how to prevent this corruption from happening programmatically, or how to fix it.  Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated!

To avoid the problem I never use BindToMoniker on closed Excel files (by checking whether the file is locked or not, if it's unlocked, I just use the open function)

Here is the code that runs when i get this problem.  It will only happen if the file exists and is not open:

```
    Public Function OpenExcelFile( _
    ByRef pobjExcel As Excel.Application, _
    ByRef pwkbWorkBook As Excel.Workbook, _
    ByVal pstrFileName As String) As Boolean
```

...

```
pwkbWorkBook = BindToMoniker(pstrFileName)
            pobjExcel = pwkbWorkBook.Parent
            pobjExcel.Visible = True 'Temp; I use this to see the state of the file
```

Comment: please Post Code you are using

Comment: Could it be that the workbook has been hidden? On the view tab, if Unhide is enabled you can reveal your hidden workbooks.

Comment: OK, the workbook was hidden!  Now i'm wondering why!?

Comment: did that fix it?  if so, @DanielCook please post as an answer, meltdownmonk please check that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that the workbook has been hidden? On the view tab, if Unhide is enabled you can reveal your hidden workbooks.

Also, if you think a workbook should be visible you can reveal it by updating the Windows visible property.

```
pobjExcel.Windows(workbookName).Visible = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add in

```
pobjExcel.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

right after where you set Excel to visible.  I believe that you are making the application visible, but the workbook still is not (at least this is the problem I have had before).  This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue in excel 2010. Earlier today I saved the file and closed excel. My computer went to sleep mode, when i restarted and opened the same excel 2010 file using windows explorer, excel just showed a blank (grey) screen. Only in VBA editor i could see the workbook was opened.

My solution (same as above but elaborated)

- open VBA editor using ALT + F11
- in the left top project explorer treeview, click the just opened workbook that does not appear in the excel front-end
- open the direct window  (CTRL + G)
- type "Windows(thisworkbook.name).Visible = True" and press enter

Comment: This is a good solution for when working within Excel only.  I was initiating the excel commands from a compiled VB.net application.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to View menu and hit Arrange all. it will give you some option check mark Tiled.

it worked for me, hopefully work for you as well.

Best,
Khan

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution worked for me: open the worksheet and go to the 'View' tab, then click 'New Window'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the whole worksheet invisible on 2015Jan01
I went to View menu and clicked "Unhide" icon
All the tabs became visible and I quicly saved again the file ;-)

Comment: I had the same issue with the whole worksheet invisible. 
I went to View menu and clicked "Unhide" icon. 
All the tabs became visible and I quickly saved again the file ;-)
I hope this helps